# Electrical outlets that allow different plug types

Tags: electrical, receptacle, uk, socket

I am based in the UK. I recently bought an extension cord where each socket accepts different plug types - UK, European, US, Australian - can all be plugged into these sockets.

[image]

This was a massively pleasant surprise, but it now made me want to get regular UK electrical outlets that support this. I'd like to get something like the below, but with the above-type sockets (USB is optional):

[image]

Doing a reverse image search on the image of the extension cord only finds extension cords or adaptors.  Reverse image search on a picture taken of a single socket finds nothing.  Does what I want even exist?  If yes, how do I search for it?

**EDIT:** In response to an answer explaining the risks of using Asian-imported, not-to-UK-code products... I have no intention installing them in the UK.  I do fully recognise and understand the risks associated with using these products.  I am interested though in installing them in my country house in a third-world country, where the standard is EU plugs, as I do have a lot of UK devices there alongside local devices.

Comment: Downvoting because 1) "third world" has no relevant meaning in this context.  Most less-developed countries have *some* standards, or at least are trying, 2) even if your country does not, why would you exploit that to install ridiculous dangerous equipment inside the walls instead of trying to adhere to some reasonable set of standards from abroad, 3) it's SO much easier, safer, cheaper, to just put local plugs on your appliances than to adapt your BUILDING to your imported electrical appliances.

Comment: Also, some gratuitous advice: In-wall USB power is a terrible waste of money for many reasons, nicely exemplified by that 15W POS in your photo.

Comment: Have you considered putting a local plug on a decent UK powerbar/extension cord? Less work, less burning down, etc etc.

Comment: @jay613 exactly, the sockets go obsolete faster than you can replace them lol.   Turns into a big waste of money.

Answer (score 2):

Virtually all the devices of the sort you show are made in Asia and not tested nor listed by any Nationally Recognized Testing Laboratory, (NRTL) being distributed by "direct import" methods that bypass little things like code requirements for such testing.

Installing them is thus normally a code violation in places (such as the UK) that have an electrical code in place, as those places require that devices be NRTL tested and listed as suitable for use in the locale.

One obvious hazard is that things with US/Japan plugs which are NOT broad voltage range computer/phone charger switching power supples will get twice the expected/rated voltage and die horribly, often in flames.

Addressing your update regarding using them in a different locale:

Search term **eu/uk multi-plug wall socket** brought up this probable fire-starter.

[image: UK-Style wall socket with multiple plug types]

*[Image Source](https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/8c389972-098f-4fff-a518-12aedd57d297.a6f77c1fccff0cf79377dc78714eaa02.jpeg?odnHeight=117&odnWidth=117&odnBg=FFFFFF&format=avif), I don't endorse **at all.***

A **far safer** (just how good *is* the Fire Department at your country house?) option would be to install UK receptacles alongside the EU receptacles in your country house for the UK-Specific appliances. UK plugs/receptacles are among the best on the planet. Multi-plug unlisted things are NOT. You should have no trouble sourcing UK receptacles, since you live in the UK.

Comment: Fair point - however it doesn't answer the question as to how to search for them :) I don't want to install them in the UK. I want to install them in my country house in a third-world country, where devices from across the world are being used.  Specifically, UK and EU plugs are of interest.

Comment: Hope you have a good third-world fire department, then.

Comment: A good hotel in Singapore had plugs like these. I would not call Singapore a third world country.

Comment: Hotels are a special case and a specialty market. If you can find out where they are getting those outlets, they probably have been properly inspected. They also probably cost significantly more than the no-nane uncertified knock-offs.

Comment: @JonCuster there are sockets looking like the one pictured here that are isolated, current-limited, shaver outlets, and they can be designed well and can be very safe.  Hard to tell from the picture if this is one of those, or a  "fire starter".

Comment: You *can* get this type of socket from *proper* manufacturers. https://buildings.honeywell.com/us/en/products/by-category/electrical-and-wiring/wiring-devices/modules/power-modules/slimline-plus-euro-power-modules [You probably pay a premium, MK are not cheap, but they pretty much invented the UK plug/socket design]

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I never said I wanted to buy cheap and save some pennies. I'm happy to pay more for the convenience - hence my question is specifically about what these things are called, so that I could search for them.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Ecnerwal's 100% correct "not approved so can't use it" answer, it is extremely important to consider that there are two vastly different voltage ranges in use around the world for ordinary plug-in appliances:

- 220V - 250V - Europe (including UK), most of Africa, most of Asia (except Japan), etc.
- 100V - 127V - US, Canada, Mexico, Japan, etc.

While a lot of modern electronics - computers, phone chargers, TVs, etc. will work on the full range of 100V - 250V, a lot of things will not - e.g., kitchen appliances (both small ones like toasters or blenders and large ones like refrigerators), space heaters, laser printers and many other things. Depending on the design voltage, the actual voltage and other factors, this can result in many different outcomes, including:

- Fire
- Meltdown
- Devices wearing out much faster than normal
- Heating too quickly (dangerous) or too slowly (ineffective)

and probably some other problems I haven't thought of. I have seen pictures of similar receptacles on some airplanes, but that is a different situation for a bunch of reasons, and even then it is very much "user beware". But at least nobody will (hopefully) be trying to plug in a toaster or refrigerator or laser printer in those funny receptacles on an airplane.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - however please look at my update on the original question.  I am specifically interested in EU-UK interoperability with both being 220-250V

Comment: Then the solution is to do what Ecnerwal recommended - install UK and EU sockets *separately* so you can plug each type of device in. A big problem with the "do everything" extension cords/outlet strips is that since no respectable organization will test/certify them, the manufacturer has **no incentive** to get the other stuff right. For example, they might scrimp on wire size to save a few pennies - which works fine a lot of the time but can cause a fire when you plug in a large appliance, with no warning.